# how can I see the amount of requests to my deployment

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have a question for you guys, about Kubernetes monitoring dashboard.

1. how can I see the number of requests to my deployment or services, such as ui-client or auth pods, and add them to my custom dashboard?
2. how can i add to my dashboard the "image version" that running on the cluster?

I did not find any relevant information within the official documentation.

Comment: Well, if you do have something related to logs (ELK / EFK stack), you potentially would be able to fetch amount of requests per every N period.

Comment: please elaborate. how do I do it?